# Is it possible to conclude that $a$ is finite and not equal infinity

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Assuming that $f_{k}=Ω(g_{k})$ where $f_{k}$, $g_{k}$ are two strictly positive non equal real sequences and $Ω$ is the Big Omega in complexity theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) then $$\liminf_{k \to \infty} f_{k}/g_{k}=a>0$$

Assuming that $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_{k} = 0$

My **question** is: Is it possible to conclude that $a$ is finite and not equal infinity.

Comment: There are two versions of $\Omega$ listed there.  Which are you using?

Comment: @DanUznanski: the Big Omega in complexity theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may miss something. But what about
$$\begin{cases}
f_k &= 1/k\\
g_k &= 1/k^2
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Downvoter... A comment would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks right to me.  Note that $\Omega$ is not defined as a tight bound, just as a bound: $g$ need not approximate $f$ very well at all.

Comment: So, the definition given in the link is wrong since $f_{k}=Ω(g_{k})$ if and only if $\liminf_{k \to \infty} f_{k}/g_{k}>0$

Comment: Or the link implicitly consider that $\infty$ is "a number" satisfying $\infty > 0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: The limit is finite if $f_{k}/g_{k}$ is bounded.